# How to let maven use local repository for dependencies

Tags: maven

I have a project with dependencies. All the JARS are available in local repository but  missing in the central /remote one. While building its always going to remote one and ignoring local repository specified in settings.xml.

Any clues will help.

Comment: Think its not ignoring, but not installed. First, mvn try locally , next, remote. See these to how install to local rep. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Comment: I'm not sure: Is your remote repo a special one configured in the settings.xml or did you configure a second local repo in the settings file?

Comment: Are your dependencies snapshots?

Answer (score 0):

Answering because I faced this issue and spent a lot of time to figure it out. I faced this issue because I forced maven to look into repository for every snapshots and release.

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>       
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
<repository>
```

Removing attributes release and snapshots from setting.xml resolved.